# Getting the next key in an array

Tags: tcl

My goal is to find the next key in an array... below my data :

```
# Index increment may change, there is not necessarily continuity like this example.
# My $index can be 1,2,3,4,8,12,25,32...
# but the size of my array is about 100,000 elements.
for {set index 1} {$index < 100000} {incr index} {
    set refdata($index,Pt,X) [expr {10 + $index}] 
}
```

I need to know the next key to be able to build a geometric line... I did not find in the help a command that allows me to find the next key of my array so I created my own function below :

```
proc SearchNextKeyArrayElement {dataarray mykey} {
    upvar $dataarray myarray

    set mydata [lsort -dictionary [array names myarray]]
    set index  [lsearch $mydata $mykey]

    if {$index > -1} {
        return [lindex $mydata [expr {$index + 1}]]
    }

    return ""
}

foreach k [lsort -dictionary [array names refdata]] {
    if {[string match "*,Pt,*" $k]} {
        set nextkey [SearchNextKeyArrayElement refdata $k]
    }
}
```

And it takes a long time...
`array nextelement` command is maybe the solution...
But I do not understand how to use it ?

Comment: I think you need to take a few steps and reconsider your design. Tcl (associative) arrays are _unordered_ by design; they don't have “next element” in any useful way (whenever you set or unset an element, the order they've got might change). If you want an order, use lists and/or dicts.

Comment: @DonalFellows, you’re probably right, but I find this command easy to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

- start a search with `array startsearch`
- loop while `array anymore` is true
- get the next key with `array nextelement`
- tidy up with `array donesearch`
- use `try {} catch {} finally` for safety

```
# array foreach
# to be subsumed in Tcl 8.7 by `array for`
# https://core.tcl.tk/tips/doc/trunk/tip/421.md
#
# example:
#   array set A {foo bar baz qux}
#   array foreach {key val} A {puts "name=$key, value=$val"}
#
# A note on performance: we're not saving any time with this approach.
# This is essentially `foreach name [array names ary] {...}
# We are saving memory: iterating over the names versus extracting
# them all at the beginning.
#
proc array_foreach {vars arrayName body} {
    if {[llength $vars] != 2} {
        error {array foreach: "vars" must be a 2 element list}
    }
    lassign $vars keyVar valueVar

    # Using the complicated `upvar 1 $arrayName $arrayName` so that any
    # error messages propagate up with the user's array name
    upvar 1 $arrayName $arrayName \
            $keyVar    key \
            $valueVar  value

    set sid [array startsearch $arrayName]
    # If the array is modified while a search is ongoing, the searchID will
    # be invalidated: wrap the commands that use $sid in a try block.
    try {
        while {[array anymore $arrayName $sid]} {
            set key [array nextelement $arrayName $sid]
            set value [set "${arrayName}($key)"]
            uplevel 1 $body
        }
    } trap {TCL LOOKUP ARRAYSEARCH} {"" e} {
        puts stderr [list $e]
        dict set e -errorinfo "detected attempt to add/delete array keys while iterating"
        return -options $e
    } finally {
        array donesearch $arrayName $sid
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I am aware that a `tcl array` does not keep the order of insertion but It is possible to use the list I have formatted (lsort -dictionary) with this command ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, Tcl arrays have no order at all; they can change their order on any modification to the array or any of its elements. The commands that iterate over the array (`array for`, `array get`, `array names`, and the iteration commands `array startsearch`/`array nextelement`/`array anymore`) only work with the current order. However, you can use `array names` to get the element names into a Tcl list (which is order preserving), sort those to get the order that you're going to iterate over, and then use `foreach` over that. As long as you're not adding or removing elements, it'll be fine. (Adding elements is sort-of OK too; you'll just not see them in your iteration.)

```
foreach key [lsort -dictionary [array names myarray]] {
    ProcessElement $key $myarray($key)
}
```

By contrast, trying to just go from one element to the next will hurt a lot; that operation is not exposed.

---

Using the iteration commands is done like this:

```
set s [array startsearch myarray]
while {[array anymore myarray $s]} {
    set key [array nextelement myarray $s]
    ProcessElement $key $myarray($key)
}
```

Note that you don't get an option to sort the search. You won't see these used much in production code; doing `array names` or `array get` is usually better. And now (well, 8.7 is still in alpha) you've also got `array for`:

```
array for {key value} myarray {
    ProcessElement $key $value
}
```

Efficient for large arrays, but still doesn't permit sorting; supporting direct sorting would require a different sort of storage engine on the back of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is why it's slow: You're sorting the array names once for the foreach command *and then again for each element*. Sort once and cache it, then you can iterate over it much more efficiently

```
set sorted_names [lsort -dictionary [array names refdata -glob {*,Pt,*}]]
set len [llength $sorted_names]
for {set i 0; set j 1} {$i < $len} {incr i; incr j} {
    set this_name [lindex $sorted_names $i]
    set next_name [lindex $sorted_names $j]
    # ...
}
```